# How can I recognise programmatically when an up/down arrow is drawn on a chart when arrow objects are hidden?

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, mt4

I know how to draw an object arrow on the chart, which I usually do like this:

```
      ObjectCreate(0,"prevHigh",OBJ_ARROW_DOWN,0,Time[0],High[highestCandle]);  
      ObjectSetInteger(0, "prevHigh", OBJPROP_COLOR, clrRed);
```

Now I have an indicator which (I didn't code myself and is a .ex4 file which) draws up/down arrows on the chart as seen in the image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYVE4.jpg).

[image]

How can I when for example a Magenta down arrow has been drawn and the candle (index) at which it is drawn?

Please note that the arrows not in the list of objects on the chart
[image]

Comment: **Can you prove, that the arrow objects drawn are *--not--* in the list of objects** ( by posting a printscreen thereof ? )

Comment: @user3666197 Here is a screenshot of the list of all objects (https://imgur.com/a/4lRea6Y)

Comment: @BBNN I am very interested in your question so I started a bounty for it.

Comment: @Hilarious404 Wow, thanks. I haven't been able to arrive at a solution yet. Hopefully this  will help

Comment: The claimed problem keeps not to be REPRODUCIBLE - would you mind, BBNN, to meet the StackOverflow Rules and post the MQL4 Custom Indicator, that you refer to have used for "producing" the PrintScreen-ed pictures? Not doing so will cause the @Hilarious404 sponsored bounty to just expire in vain.

Comment: @Hilarious404 I was able to get it done yesterday, I'll provide an answer soon

Comment: @BBNN Hi, I would like to know if you reached to solution on how to check if the arrow exists and how to get its value/color for example? I'm facing same issue for custom indicator for which i don't have the original code...can you share the details?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"How can I recognise programmatically **when** an up/down arrow is drawn on a chart?"*

Given the facts above, your test ought evaluate the moment the CustomIndicator ( via a published / used **`iCustom()`**-call signature ) by checking it as it goes from **`EMPTY_VALUE`** to any value **`!= EMPTY_VALUE`**.

Given the CustomIndicator is a closed source ( `*.ex4` ) you may need to check, if it did set its own ( hidden from our sight ) value, other than a current visible `EMPTY_VALUE`, yet this "re-calibration" will work, after you get a few manual tests of the CustomIndicator values for bars, that do not show any arrow - like for the 2020-Apr-08 09:30 et al v/s the displayed arrows are not the MQL4-Objects on their own, they are the closed-source CustomIndicator's `SetIndexStyle()` / `SetIndexArrow()` by-products, thus not inspectable either in the Object-List, or in the `*.mq4` source-code.

***Yet, detectable***

Comment: I am not sure if I'm testing for `EMPTY_VALUE` in the right way. Please see my test code https://pastebin.com/ub8FAMzH. It is never satisfied. I kept adding parameters to iCustom till I got the error `Super Signal CHFJPY,M15: array out of range in 'Super Signal.mq4' (398,14) ` in the experts tab. I'll really appreciate some more detail into how I should go about the checking for `EMPTY_VALUE`.

Comment: With all due respect, StackOverflow **strongly discourages from creeping** the original problem definition. Feel free to open any other question(s) as you feel you need MCVE-based problem solution advice and start to accept the best answers previously sponsored by actively contributing Community members and  delivered to you, that's fair - isn't it? Adding *this* and *that* and *also what about something else* is simply **not** the way StackOverflow works. Be fair and best comply with the Community Netiquette ( which all users claimed to do comply with, during the signup, didn't we? )